# Use Tomcat to serve a directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, file

I have a directory on a linux box that I want to make publicly readable using Tomcat (5.5).  I think this is easy to set up but can't find the appropriate documentation.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although Tomcat is a good web server, it's not particularly made to list directories.

You might want to look at a web server like the [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) web server instead, it's more designed for this type of thing.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible by defining that directory as an web application, but it's not really what Tomcat is designed to do, other servers are far better at serving static content.

The way to define a directory as a webapp is to either

- put it into `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`,
- configure it in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml` or
- provide a context `.xml` file and put it in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost` (by default, depends on your configuration).

Answer (score 2):

You can just link it to a folder under webapps as a new "web application".

```
ln -s /path-to-real-folder /path-to-tomcat/webapps/publicfoldername
```

If I remember correctly, directory listing is enabled by default in tomcat, so the dir would be reachable. If not, this can be fixed in web.xml